# I just asked a question and received some cryptic responses

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, undelete-request

What bloody good is it for you to delete a [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197081/need-assistance-with-javascript-css-and-xml) of mine without allowing for a conversation between myself and this moderator person?

I thought this might be a useful site, but this initial experience has caused me to rethink that.

Unlock my question so that I may have an intelligent conversation with "moderator" and find out just what it is y'all have to offer other than mindless aggravation.

Comment: Could you include a link to the question you're referring to?

Comment: I think it was a programming question here rather than on SO

Comment: @JohnPalmer I only see [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18819445/2001600), but I can't see deleted questions on most SE sites, including SO, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197081/need-assistance-with-javascript-css-and-xml

Comment: You posted your question in the wrong place. That's why it was deleted. It belongs on [so]. You posted it here on Meta Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, you might want to check which site you're on. This is Meta Stack Overflow, the site about Stack Overflow (and the Stack Exchange engine, for historical reasons). Stack Overflow, the programming site, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/). If it was an innocent mistake, don't feel bad about it - it happens more often than you might think. You are not alone. (If you're question-banned on SO, however, posting here won't help - see [the definitive guide to question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/223030).)

Secondly, this very question could have been written better. The help center has specific guidance here:

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - ...
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

As is written somewhere else in the help center (I'll look it up sometime), we're all humans here. Stay calm, and post on SO.

(Also, if you just wanted to discuss the deletion of your question, you've done the right thing - that's one of the purposes of Meta questions.)

Answer (score 7):

If you posted a programming question on **Meta**, then it's par for the course for that to be closed and removed - those sorts of questions are off topic on Meta.

Depending on what the question was, or the quality of it, I'd say it's a candidate for StackOverflow; but if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18819445/1079354) is similar, I'd say not.

The big thing is, you're asking not for [specific things](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); you're asking for concepts or general "help me with this one part".  Those are frowned upon here.

I don't know until I can see the question for myself, but it has to fit within the scope which is described in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

I know it can be frustrating at first, but once you learn the ways of Stack, it is most definitely an excellent resource, better than forums when you don't want chatter and just an answer to your question etc.

Although there will be mistakes made now and then as people are, well, human, usually if something is closed, locked, on hold, etc, it's for a good reason.
In this case, as has been said, you posted a programming question on meta, which is for discussing other sites, such as Stack Overflow where your question would be suited (within the rules/guidelines).

If you still disagree or are unsure of a decision, you can search here on Meta as it'll likely have been asked before. Ask away if not (but be prepared for some smarty pants mod/high rank user to dig out a dupe from the back of beyond :P).
However keep it friendly, factual etc. Rants won't be taken kindly, just as I'm sure you probably dislike and potentially ignore people ranting at you.

> What bloody good is it for you to delete a question of mine without allowing for a conversation between myself and this moderator person.

Firstly, a lot of things done here is by mutual voting of higher ranking members, not by any one person. Also, another one of numerous reasons why there isn't and wont ever likely be a 1-1 with mods, StackOVerflow Totals:
5.7 million questions;
10 million answers;
2.4 million users;

Can you imagine being a mod, with those above stats if they allowed direct contact to whoever closed a question? As a mod I'd null route my email address for sure...